# Marker Clustering (Leaflet.markercluster) with react-leaflet 2.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

Trying to get Leaflet.markercluster working with react-leaflet 2.

https://github.com/OpenGov/react-leaflet-cluster-layer does not appear to be compatible with 2.x.

Any example code to get me started is appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make your React wrapper using native leaflet code to achieve a marker cluster layer:

```
const mcg = L.markerClusterGroup();

const MarkerCluster = ({ markers }) => {
  const { map } = useLeaflet();

  useEffect(() => {
    mcg.clearLayers();
    markers.forEach(({ position, text }) =>
      L.marker(new L.LatLng(position.lat, position.lng), {
        icon: customMarker
      })
        .addTo(mcg)
        .bindPopup(text)
    );

    // optionally center the map around the markers
    // map.fitBounds(mcg.getBounds());
    // // add the marker cluster group to the map
    map.addLayer(mcg);
  }, [markers, map]);

  return null;
};
```

and then use it like this:

```
 <Map center={position} zoom={2} style={mapStyle} maxZoom={20}>
        <TileLayer
          url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
        <MarkerCluster markers={markers} />
</Map>
```

I included a case in the demo where you can change the cluster group layer using a button.

Hopefully this will get you started.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/marker-clustering-leafletmarkercluster-with-react-leaflet-20-kvxxr)

Comment: Thanks so much, @kboul. Exactly the start I was looking for. Also just discovered this existed: https://github.com/YUzhva/react-leaflet-markercluster It looks like the `@next` version supports react-leaflet@2

Comment: In this case, how could I pass a popup with a button and a `onClickListener` in it? If I render my custom popup component to string the `onClickListener` won't work..

Comment: @leverglowh Your question is beyond the scope of the current question. Please ask it in a new thread.

Comment: The lib and the doc have been updated. `<Popup onClick={}>Text<Popup>` works just fine.

Comment: did something change in the last 4 years - `markerClusterGroup` doesn't seem to be included in the default leaflet lib anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

Make sure you install the compatible versions:

- react-leaflet-markercluster v2.0.0 or 2.0.0-rc3
- leaflet 1.7.1
- react-leaflet any version 2 will work
- import 'react-leaflet-markercluster/dist/styles.min.css'